# @ManyToMany Hibernate Error: "Target Entity is not defined" + "The attribute type for a collection mapping must be java.util.Collection..."

Tags: hibernate, collections, many-to-many, entity, target

I am trying to create a ManyToMany relation between two Entity-Classes: Produkt.java and Punkt.java. I did it exactly as the hibernate documentation and various tutorials show, and it seems to work, but I get 2 Errors on both of the @ManyToMany-Annontations in both of the Entity-Classes.

The errors are:

- "Target entity is not defined"
- "The attribute type for a collection mapping must be
  java.util.Collection, java.util.Set, java.util.List or java.util.Map"

And here are the relevant parts of the code:

**Produkt.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "produkt")
public class Produkt {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    long productId;
    .
    .
    .

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "PRODUKT_PUNKT", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PUNKT_ID", 
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Punkt>punkte;

    public Produkt() {
    }

    public Produkt(List<Punkt>punkte) {
        this.punkte = punkte;
    }

    public List<Punkt> getPunkte() {
        return punkte;
    }

    public void setPunkte(List<Punkt> punkte) {
        this.punkte = punkte;
    }
}
```

**Punkt.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "punkt")
public class Punkt {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PUNKT_ID")
    private long punktId;

    .
    .
    .

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "punkte")
    private List<Produkt>produkte;

    public Punkt() {
    }

    public Punkt(List<Produkt>produkte) {
        this.produkte = produkte;
    }

    public List<Produkt> getProdukte() {
        return produkte;
    }

    public void setProdukte(List<Produkt> produkte) {
        this.produkte = produkte;
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml** (lies in /src - folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <mapping class="org.duct.ductbased.model.Produkt" />
            <mapping class="org.duct.ductbased.model.Punkt" />
        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

As mentioned, this whole construct seems to work - I can run the application, I can create instances of both classes, fill them with data and persist to the database. The only problem now seems to be that the two lines with @ManyToMany - Annotations are marked red in eclipse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And please let me know, if more information is needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@JoinTable(name = "PRODUKT_PUNKT"
```

While in your `Punkt` class you have defined

```
@Table(name = "punkt")
public class Punkt
```

It should be

```
@Table(name = "PRODUKT_PUNKT")
public class Punkt
```

In other words: `@JoinTable` name param should match the name defined with `@Table` on the other end.

Comment: Isah, thank you for such a quick reply. Unfortunately, changing the List to a Set didn't change anything (also, the error message says, that the type for a collection mapping can be a list).

Comment: For the second error message you're right. I misread the problem. I'm not sure what causes that.

Comment: isah, thank you a lot for your answer. It helped me understand the construct of those @ManyToMany - annotations (wrote it in my post underneath).

Comment: Unfortunately cannot vote up, because I don't have enough reputation. Will come back, when I have enough :)

Comment: Glad it helped, don't worry about not voting up :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after searching and trying things out, I finally got the answers for the both problems:

1. "The target entity is not defined" was caused by the false name of the second table, as isah already wrote. 
   But, it was not a coincidence, but a misunderstanding of the fundamental way of working of the entity mapping on my side. All the tutorials use a third table, to link the two tables. I actually thought, that it is what hibernate is doing in the background, when I use the @ManyToMany - Annotation, since I use the internal example database, which gets created and dropped every time I deploy the application.
2. "The attribute type for a collection mapping must be java.util.Collection, java.util.Set, java.util.List or java.util.Map" message is an unsolved JBoss bug.

   https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-16016

   It was still there, even when I deleted all the collections and the @ManyToMany parts. It disappeared, when I commented out the constructors. Now I inserted the constructors back again and the errors are not there.